# future perfect or will-future with "by the year..." or "by then"?

Tags: grammar, tense, adverbs, will-shall, future

I wonder if I always need future perfect in sentences with "by the year ..." and "by then" or if using the will-future (simple or progressive) is also possible in the two sentences below. If the latter is the case, is there a difference in meaning?

1. Scientists say that by the year 2050, the world population ***will have increased*** (Or: ***will increase?/ will be increasing?***) to almost 10 billion people.
2. If we do nothing against global warming, the temperature ***will have risen*** (Or: ***will rise?/ will be rising?***) by three degrees Celsius by then.

Comment: will increase and will be increasing is just like the present simple and present progressive.

Answer (score 1):

If the prediction is that the population will be 10 billion *in* 2050, it **will have increased** to that number by then.

During the next 28 years it **will increase**.